# bootstrap thumbnail padding

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

this is my code :

```
 @for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                    {
                        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/800x500" alt="">
                                <div class="">
                                    <h3>Feature Label</h3>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                                    <p>
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Buy Now!</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">More Info</a>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
```

how can i reduce the margin between each item ( check attachment please)

thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.col-lg-2.col-md-3.col-sm-4.col-xs-12
{
    padding: 0 your desired padding/2;
}
```

actually, it is padding. not margin.

here is the bootply example:- http://www.bootply.com/4yqAuLl9tM